# Include Django URLs in Sphinx documentation?

Tags: python, django, python-sphinx

In the interests of staying DRY as possible, I am using Sphinx with autodoc for documenting my Django project. I'm currently adding some docstrings to show the URL endpoints to reach certain functionality, but in doing some I'm duplicating what is already defined in my `urls.py` files.

Is there a way to include references to URLs within docstrings and have them processed by Sphinx such that the more extended URLs are shown in the documentation?

Comment: When you say comments, do you actually mean docstrings?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Modified original question.